# Can a C++ class export several different stl-style iterators?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I have a class that encapsulates an exotic data structure. For the sake of this question, let's say it is a `Container` of a ball of `Thingy`s.

We have many places where we iterate over the `Thingy`s in this container, but there are several different ways to do so - they can be iterated in order A or B and also there are subsets X and Y, so there's (say) four permutations of how Thingys can be iterated (subset X in order A, subset X in order Y, etc).

I would like create a custom iterator `Container` so that I can loop over `Thingy`s using C++'s range-based for syntax. **Is it possible to export multiple different iterators from a class?** Obviously I can't just have

```
class Container { 
  ...
  iter begin();
  iter end();
}
```

because there will be four different kinds of `iter`. **So how do I tell my range-based for which kind of `iter` to use?**

---

I should add that this is in an utterly performance-critical context, so we can't tolerate the cost of a callback function here. Otherwise I'd use a map(λ) type deal, but in this case we are sweating nanoseconds and if an iterator incurs an extra indirect function call (therefore branch mispredict), I'll have to stick with using our current ugly way of iterating the container.

Comment: I assume you don't just mean constant versus non-constant iterators? But e.g. forward versus reverse iterators? Unfortunately ranged-for only uses `begin` and `end`, nothing else.

Comment: You could have a few purpose-specific proxy objects that each expose begin/end pairs of their own. `for (auto& x : my_container.some_range())`

Comment: @KerrekSB If you expand your comment into an answer, I can upvote it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It's more like "forward" vs "forward with filter X" vs "in an order specified by a different structure entirely"

Comment: @Crashworks: I think Yakk has already provided an answer that is strictly more general and subsumes my suggestion as a special case :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You write a range.

```
template<class It>
struct range_t {
  It s, f;
  It begin() const { return s; }
  It end() const { return f; }
};
template<class It>
range_t<It> range( It s, It f ) { return {std::move(s), std::move(f)}; }
```

Now you expose methods that return `range_t` of the appropriate iterator type for your various ways of iterating.

These can be member functions, or friend free functions, depending on what syntax you want.

The way the iteration occurs can be hard coded in the type system, eliminating any "callback" overhead, and `range_t` are lightweight enough that they should be completely optimized away.

(Note that the above is a *very* stripped down `range_t`: a real one might have `empty`, `front`, `back`, `range_t without_front(size_t)`, and even `operator[]` support conditionally if the iterators are random access).

Comment: To provide closure on this: Yakk's suggestion worked, but a range-based for ended up being 2x slower than doing the manual horrible `for` loop we had in place (that looks up an array with indices from a lookaside buffer filtered by yet another buffer etc), so ultimately we can't use a range-for in this circumstance.

Comment: @Crashworks Odds are I can make the iterator version match the manual horrible for loop.

Comment: Sadly NDA precludes me from sharing a representative code snippet (and the stripped-down one I tried to make doesn't manifest the problem). I did tinker around with it with the generated assembly in a side window for quite a while... it seems that VC++ insists on copying around the iterator objects quite vigorously.

If I find a way to reproduce the problem in a code snippet, I'll post a blog about it and come back here to invite your feedback.

Comment: @Crashworks Well, consider stuffing more state into the "range" object (it need not be as naked as my iterator above), and having only the things that mutate over the iteration in the iterator.  The only real downside of pre-C++17 `for(:)` loops is the lack of the Sentinal option (so you need to use a "flag" to mark the end iterator, with the branch cost; highly predictable, but costs  you a branch cache entry).  And yes, iterators should be optimized to be dirt cheap to copy.  A pointer to state in the range object for "loop shared state" can work wonders.